# how to schedule job with start and end?

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I want to schedule a apex classes through apex code and need to have a cron expression with a fix startdate & enddate.
It needs to be also possible to set the startdate & enddate like below:

*-Start: 30.10.2014*

*-End: 6.02.2015*

*-Time: 00:00*

*-Daily*

How can i handle this issues ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Crone expression it is not possible. However, as a workaround, in your Scheduler you can check date every time before execution. If you find date then remove Scheduled job from Queue.

You can check this documentation to query CronTrigger - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

Also, you can check this URL which will help you to make Cron expressions- http://www.cronmaker.com/